# Multiply a column using awk

Tags: text-processing, scripting, awk

How do I multiply a column by an integer (say 3) and replace the older value by new one, using `awk`?

Input:

```
Data     9390.900391 10573.089844    80.000000   200.000000     2.700000
Data    17762.810547 18536.189453    85.000000   200.000000     2.700000
```

Expected output: (after multiplying the last column by 3)

```
Data     9390.900391 10573.089844    80.000000   200.000000     8.100000
Data    17762.810547 18536.189453    85.000000   200.000000     8.100000
```

Comment: Do you need to retain the column formatting? Note that the simple way to do this (as given in cuonglm's answer) separates each field by a single space.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ awk 'NF{$NF = sprintf("%.6f", $NF*3)}1' file
Data 9390.900391 10573.089844 80.000000 200.000000 8.100000
Data 17762.810547 18536.189453 85.000000 200.000000 8.100000
```

Change `$NF` to the `$n` where `n`is the field you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop:

```
awk '/^$/{next}; {for(i=1;i<=5;i++){printf "%s\t", $i}; printf "%.6f\n", $6*3}' file 
Data    9390.900391     10573.089844    80.000000       200.000000      8.100000
Data    17762.810547    18536.189453    85.000000       200.000000      8.100000
```

Comment: This will print `0.00000` in 6th column of a blank line.

Comment: @cuonglm Fixed...

Comment: Thank you Jason. It also fixes the column formatting. Great !